# Corona SDK widget.newButton() not appearing in simulator when inside scene:create

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have the following code:

```
function scene:create( event )

  local sceneGroup = self.view

  -- Initialize the scene here.
  -- Example: add display objects to "sceneGroup", add touch listeners, etc.

  local options1 = {
    x = display.contentWidth / 2,
    y = 200,
    onRelease = button,
    lableAlign = "center",
    emboss = true,
    id = "1",
    label = "Button1"
  }

  local options2 = {
    y = 300,
    x = display.contentWidth / 2,
    onRelease = button,
    lableAlign = "center",
    emboss = true,
    id = "2",
    label = "Button2"
  }

  local button1 = widget.newButton(options1)
  local button2 = widget.newButton(options2)
  sceneGroup:insert(button1)
  sceneGroup:insert(button2)
end
```

When I place this code in a standalone file (not a scene) the buttons show up as supposed. However now I am turning this standalone file into a scene and for some reason the above code results in nothing in the simulator. Any ideas?

Comment: We are going to need a bit more code - show us how you transition into the scene and did you include widget in the new scene?

Comment: This is within my main.lua file. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Ok. Added an answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. move your scene the a `yourScene.lua` file (named as you wish) in which you call `storyboard.newScene()` (no argument) and in your `main.lua` you use `storyboard.goto('yourScene')`
2. you can create the scene in `main.lua` via `storyboard.newScene('yourScene')` and goto it from within main.lua via `storyboard.goto('yourScene')`

Basically your scene can be in a separate module, corona automatically names it based on module name, and main.lua goes to it, or your scene can be in same module, but then you have to give it a name yourself, and main.lua can "goto" it (within same module). You can even have multiple scenes in same module.

I recommend you have your scenes in separate modules, it just makes for better modularization. Conjecture: maybe the method 2 was the original, and method 1 was added latter when developers found their scenes were getting large and so needed to move them to separate modules.

Answer (score 2):

The code posted above is within the main.lua file. Therefore, the scene is never called. The solution is to rename the file above to something like menu.lua and then call this scene from main.lua.